# What is the maximum number of items allowed in your inventory?

Tags: card-hunter

Is there a maximum number of items in your inventory? If so, how many items can you hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consensus on the Card Hunter forums seems to be that there is no limit to the number of items that your inventory can hold*. [Here's a link](https://forums.cardhunter.com/threads/max-number-of-items-in-bank.3528/) to a thread on the official forums discussing the matter.

**Of course when you're dealing with computers, there has to be some upper limit on the inventory size, but in this case it seems to be so high that it can effectively be treated as non-existant.*